# Selecting specific indexes for instances on points node - Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

Selecting specific indexes for instances on points node.

I know a can use the **Selection** option on the **Instances on Points** node to choose the indexes to use, but how can I choose more than just two specific indexes.  (I would like to choose the indexes **0,2,3,7,8,13,121**)

The thing I've tried is boolean's and that seems to stop working after 2 indexes.

[image: img1]

Is there a list node where I could just type the numbers in to use that as the index selection?

Comment: Booleans are working with any count with me. How are you connecting the booleans? These aren't connected in the image in your question.

Comment: @Hulifier `I didn't have issues connecting the geometry so I just left that out, it was the selecting multiple specific indexes I had the issues with`. Are several + Boolean's nodes the only way to do this?

Comment: What @Hulifier probably means, is, that you should connect the output of the upper Or node to the input of the lower one. And you should connect the output of the lower Or node with the Selection input.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/249570/60486 https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/277610/60486 https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/275939/60486 https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/274666/60486

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already mentioned, you could connect the output of the upper Or node to the input of the lower one. And you should connect the output of the lower Or node with the Selection input.

A completely different approach could be, to use a meshline object as a selection mask. In this example, I created a 1x10 grid, that I use as selection mask. If the z-position of one point is > 0, this means "on".

[image: demo 1]

[image: demo 2]

A second object has the following Geometry Nodes net attached.

[image: node net]

This instantiates 10 icospheres. Depending on the positions of the vertices of the input object, the icospheres are "turned on" or "off". The above mentioned grid is used as this input object.

Answer (score 2):

You can select multiple indexes by feeding the next boolean node with the previous.

[image: Selection by boolean comparisons with index]

As far as my search goes, there's no lists in Geometry nodes. Maybe there's a hack workaround with python? I don't know until that moment.