# Geometry Nodes - Extrude edge by ID

Tags: geometry-nodes

I want to be able to extrude edges of a mesh by ID number - e.g. extrude edge 2 and 3.
Is this possible? I see the selection input socket of the node requires a boolean input, and I saw the post linked below where they create a 'mask' to feed into the socket. How would I build this mask using integers? Presumably, a list containing boolean values like 0,1,1,0 would work. But I can't see a way to build this list.

[How can i extrude specific edges in geometry nodes?](https://blenderartists.org/t/how-can-i-extrude-specific-edges-in-geometry-nodes/1368644/2)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured out a way to parse a string into a list of booleans:

[image]

**Custom Group** (hidden text settings don't matter, as long as they're in sync)

[image]

[image] [image]

Comment: This looks good... How did you input the list? I can't figure that much out :-/

Comment: @G.H. when you press N key to open numbers panel in the geonodes tree editor, you will see a tab to specify inputs, you can add a string input here. Alternatively, if you connect an "empty" *Group Input* socket to a socket of type string, a new input will automatically be created of that type.

Comment: Ahh! I didn't see that tab. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The concept of using a string to control the individual edges is strictly speaking an abuse of *Geometry Nodes*, but I'll let it stand anyway ;-)

Anyway, the idea can be refined and improved a bit:

[image]

Here I simply replace the number $0$ with a space (**Note:** Unfortunately you can't see it on the screenshot, but here it is important that you insert a space (<kbd>␣</kbd>) in the *Replace* field!).

The node `String to Curves` creates an instance, but the output *Pivot Point* has then the value $(0,0,0)$. After that it is easy to derive a boolean value from it, which can be used directly as a selection.

Comment: I was thinking about optimizing my setup for booleans... You probably noticed I set txt box width because it's a simplification of multi-digit numbers

Comment: Where does that "Lenght" node come from? I can't find it...

Comment: @G.H. This is a vector math node. Here you can find more information if you are looking for a specific node: [Can't find the node! Which node is available in which Blender version?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/273542/145249)

Comment: @quellenform, Thanks - the colour threw me off.  In that case, this doesn't work for me. I've tried the same setup, but I find that if ANY value of the string is a 1, then ALL edges are extruded. If ALL values are 0, then no edges are extruded - but there is no individual control. I'm using Blender 3.3.0.

Comment: @G.H. Please be so kind and share your blend file. The error can surely be found easily: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Here you go:

https://blend-exchange.com/b/jAenxgw5/ - Extrude Edges by String.blend

Comment: @G.H. You did everything right, but unfortunately it was not clear in the screenshot (I added a note to the answer): You would have to enter a space in the *Replace* field for the second `Replace String` node. This will replace the number $0$ with a character that has no geometry and thus has the length $0$.

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass this list of integers to the geometry nodes setup somehow… You can combine simple comparisons with *Boolean ORs*:

[image]

You can more easily control more points (up to 31) using a *ColorRamp* node like in these answers:

[How can I rotate individual curve points in geometry nodes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/275947/60486)

[Cycling /looping through a set of index values using geometry nodes to create animation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/274681/60486)

However, in your case it seems you want to input a list from outside… You can take a look here:

[How to instantiate objects on individual/selected points in geometry nodes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/249580/60486)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using a binary bitflag integer input.

[image]

[image]

It can be extended to an arbitrary number of indices up to 10, since it's elevated to 10^input it produces very high numbers. Higher values will produce negative numbers and fail.

[image]

Note if there would exist a "String to Value" node and if "Slice String" were to accept a field, this limitation could be lifted and a string input could be used.

Comment: Very nice solution! ...but isn't it limited to a maximum of 10 digits?

Comment: Yup, it is, unfortunately ! :) If we could slice a string into a field and have a "String to Value" field node I think we could get past this limit, since strings are (theoretically) not limited in size.

Comment: This is what I'm doing [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/249580/60486) except you're smart enough to do it the easier way, you calculate the power and compare, rather than doing a logarithm. BTW, like I mention under the link, you can't start with a 0...

Comment: I updated that answer and argue there the maximum number of booleans stored in an integer is actually $7$, not 10! At least unless you're willing to make the first zeroes invisible, in such case it would be 8. `np.float32(111111111) == 111111110.0`

Comment: Indeed, interesting ! Thanks for doing the computation.

Comment: Another update, by using base 2 you can store up to 24 booleans.