# Using Geometry Nodes. How do I make each characters in a string to become specific 3D Objects?

Tags: geometry-nodes, text-object

Using Geometry Nodes, how do I make each character in a string of letters, numbers and symbols become a specific 3d object? I'd like to let the user enter a string of characters and this will help create a 3D sign with said letters.

I can't use the *String to Curve* node. While it is good, there are symbols I need that are not in the font and I also need control over the font geometry to keep it low poly count.

Comment: Currently the only way to process a string character by character is the String to Curve node. Even when [converting a string to an array of booleans](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/277627/60486), I use this node for that reason. If some characters are not in the font, then simply use another font or create a new font for that reason. You could also replace some characters with other characters, but that's only reasonable for a low number of replacements…

Comment: Thank you. I was worried I'd need to make a new font. I've done it before a few years ago, Was just hoping I could avoid that.